# using wildcards word 2013

Tags: c#, ms-word, wildcard

I try to find this kind of expression in my Word document :

```
@HELLO_WORLD@
```

I use this code :

```
word.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
word.Selection.Find.Text = @"<\@*\@>";
```

But I don't have any result.
I tried the same expression in Word Find window, but I didn't find result too.

Answer (score 1):

sorry I found the right wildcard. I think that Word considers @ not like a beggining of a word.

```
\@<*>\@
```